# IF Statement For Javascript

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-ui, if-statement, modal-dialog

I'm looking Jquery UI's [modal form demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/modal-form.html). But i want to add something.
This demo checking all inputs' (name,email,password)  lenght and validate them. But email input must be *optional*. Because of this i'm setting email input's min value (*for checkLength() function*) to zero. But when i leave blank email input i'm getting validation error. You can check full codes [here](http://jsfiddle.net/teknoblogo/rFEj7/) .

It's validation email with this code :

```
bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( email, ..SOME REGEX PATTERNS WILL COME HERE.., "eg. ui@jquery.com" );
```

But i want to try validation only if there is any email input. Because email input is optional and visitors can leave it. How can i add **if statement** (if email input is filled, validate it. Else don't try validation) to this code ?
I hope it's clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are saying "how to do validation only if email is not empty?", then I see no reason this wouldn't work:

```
var email = $( "#email" ); // taken from the linked code
if (email.val() != "") { // e-mail field value is not empty
  bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( email, ..SOME REGEX PATTERNS WILL COME HERE.., "eg. ui@jquery.com" );
}
```

Note: if you actually have no idea how to use conditional statements in JS, you may have a **lot** of hurdles ahead of you. See [this](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/javascript/if_else_switch.php) for a quick reference, and/or get a book about JS basics.

Comment: i'm trying to use `email.lenght === 0` condition but it's not work. I'll try this. thank you.

Comment: @Eray: You're welcome. Where did you get that syntax? First, `lenght` is probably a typo; second, this would get you a number of elements matching `#email` - [see the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/length/).